# How to use ng-model and ng-bind with php call in angular?

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-bind

```
<div class="controls">
    <select ng-model="company_name" name="com_id" class="span2 company ter_filter insert">
        <option value="">-- Select Company --</option>
        <?php
        $com=mysql_query("select * from `company_tbl` where `org_id`='$_SESSION[org_id]'");
        while($com1=mysql_fetch_array($com))
        {?>
        <option value="<? echo $com1['com_id'];?>"><?echo $com1['com_name'];?></option>
        <?}
        ?>
    </select>                                               
</div>
```

> this is my code to fetch records from db using php and ajax call.

now i want to display com_name with

`Company Name:{{company_name}}` this ng-bind.
i am getting `com_id` in `Company Name:{{company_name}}`. please help me to get `com_name` with  `Company Name:{{company_name}}`

Comment: update full code